# Intellij Java: Jni error has occured

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, jar, java-native-interface

I've looked at many of the other similar questions posted but it seems that a lot of it is about exporting and using a .Jar file.

I'm trying to only compile my code. I had it on github but when I cloned and tried to compile the same program on a new computer, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/uiDesigner/core/Spacer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am currently using jdk 1.8, if anyone can help me compile my program it'll be great, here's a snippet of the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CertifyGUI");
    frame.setContentPane(new CertifyGUI().panelMain);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile an intellij plugin? I can't explain the reason to have intellij specific packages.

Comment: @PieterDeBie Yes, it's Intellij's GUI builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses classes from IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer, for this code to compile and run you need to include these classes in the classpath and build the code from IntelliJ IDEA or using `javac2` Ant task.

The missing classes are available in `IDEA_HOME\redist\forms_rt.jar`.

When building from IntelliJ IDEA, the required classes are copied to the output directory (classpath) automatically and the `.class` files are instrumented with the GUI initialization code based on the `.form` files.

There are ways to build it with Maven/Gradle/Ant in the command line, you can Google the relevant answers if that is what you need (`javac2 maven`, `javac2 gradle`, etc).

Comment: Mind me asking where this path is located? I can't seem to find it

Comment: `IDEA_HOME` is the directory where you've installed IntelliJ IDEA.